# Private struct methods

Tags: go

My understanding of struct methods is that they are tightly coupled with interfaces.

Basically, from https://gobyexample.com/methods

> Interface is mechanism for grouping and naming related set of methods.

In various codes (and it's something that I was doing originally), I see private struct methods.
And I don't think this makes much sense since those methods are not part of the interface so IMO it makes the code more confusing.

So my question is simple: does it make sense to have private struct method? Why?

Comment: *"My understanding of struct methods is that they are tightly coupled with interfaces."* This is incorrect. It's true that to implement an interface you first need to declare the methods defined by that interface, however the methods themselves have no dependency on the interface that they are implementing. If you would take the interface construct out of the language, the method construct would still work the same, unaltered.

Comment: Also methods do not have to be struct methods. Any **kind** of type can implement any\* interface. \*as long that interface is declared in the same package as the type or all of the interfaces methods are exported (with exported types in their signatures).

Comment: @mkopriva "Any kind of type can implement any* interface" is a bit of an exaggeration: Pointer types like `type P *int` cannot carry methods and thus cannot implement interfaces, but that is jsut academic nitpicking.

Comment: @Volker you're right, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [D]oes it make sense to have private struct method?

Yes.

> Why?

For the same reason as for exported ("public") methods:

1. To satisfy an interface (exported or unexported).
2. To group operations on types, keep package namespace uncluttered and organise your code.

Comment: Hey Volker, thanks for your answer. So does having private functions without interfaces makes sense then? If yes, since private functions are already privates to a package, how making them struct methods help to organize the code?

Comment: @bappr: being struct methods, they are scoped to the struct type. This way you can have, say, a `count()` method on each of your structs without them clashing with each other.

Comment: @bappr You are asking "does having private functions without interfaces makes sense" which makes no sens to ask as functions and interfaces are unrelated concepts and being exported or not doesn't change this. _Methods_ do not clutter the package namespace. Think of 10 types all allowing to be frobricated. You can equip each type with a `frobricate()` method or write 10 times a `frobricateTypeA(a *TypeA)` function. Also: There are no public or private things in Go.  A package _exports_ things or doesn't. The correct term is exported/not exported.

Comment: Ok I think I see it now. Thanks ;)